# avoid the auto increase font size c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, font-size

I am using MasterPage and using using a CSS in master page. My problem is in its content page, I have a messgage box comes up in some condition resulting FONT SIZE INCREASE. I do not have any font specification in my content page. I do not know how my content page font size change when I click on "OK" to my message box.

Please suggest me some solution.

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, that's pretty weird. Can you reproduce the problem in a new, very concise page? If so, post it here.

Comment: You are right! when I tried in a new page that was just having some text, font did not increased. Now I am more curious,why its happening in some forms only... any thought about it?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Clearly you *could* be changing the font style somehow, after the click ends, but that seems unlikely. Is the font zoomed in on your browser? Check that that is set to normal, and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of it. Initially the problem cause was, click on 'ok' to message box which was generated by JavaScript 'alert'. I tried to put MessageBox from System.Windows.Forms reference.
Using MessageBox ,got the solution.

But I did not understand the reason, why using 'alert' was causing problem.
If someone can throw light on it, it would be helpful for me and may be for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

How are you applying you styles? Are you doing it with Javascript or some framework?

If that's the case obviously some sort of error could result in a page reset, or the page dropping the styles and going to a default rendering.

You really need to post code for a better response.

Comment: i think, you were right, i was using java script which have caused the problem by reseting the page.

Comment: upvotes and correct answer checks are always appreciated.  :)